# What is a RanchWord™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee)*

If a word follows a certain rule it is called a **RanchWord™**. Here are some examples:

| RanchWords™ | Not RanchWords™ |
| --- | --- |
| AMUSED | PLEASED |
| ARREST | DETAIN |
| SHORTEST | TALLEST |
| DEFERRED | DENIED |
| ATOMS | MOLECULES |
| THERMOMETERS | BAROMETERS |
| FOOT | ANKLE |
| FARM | RANCH |
| SOUTHEAST | NORTHWEST |

CSV:

```
RanchWords™,Not RanchWords™
AMUSED,PLEASED
ARREST,DETAIN
SHORTEST,TALLEST
DEFERRED,DENIED
ATOMS,MOLECULES
THERMOMETERS,BAROMETERS
FOOT,ANKLE
FARM,RANCH
SOUTHEAST,NORTHWEST
```

What is the rule to tell whether a word is a RanchWord™ or not? Why are they called RanchWords™, especially since "Ranch" **ISN'T** one?

(Note that each word can be tested for whether it is a RanchWord™ on its own, without looking at any of the other words in the list of examples.)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Maybe a small hint?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (probably wrong) guess:

> BLINK-182 is an American rock band whose second album was called "Dude RANCH".

So, a RanchWord is any word

> that excludes any of the letters B L I N K. They are 'fenced out'.
>  All RanchWords, for example 'Amused', do not contain B, L, I, N, or K.
>  All Non-RanchWords, for example 'Pleased', contain at least one B, L, I, N, or K.
>  Observations:
>  Normally ranches fence things *in*, so this is probably wrong.
>  The full set of fenced out letters is Plnicbkw, so any rule related to 'ranch' that involves these letters stands a chance of being right.

Comment: see my answer. :)

Comment: look at my comment.

Answer (score 0):

### **Partial answer:**

I have noticed that:

> All of the RanchWords have letters only in this set: ADEFHMORSTU

Still trying to figure out the connection between those letters, though.

Comment: Any hints yet? I am still puzzled.

Comment: Well, it has been about 12 days now. Any clues whatsoever?